# Debugging App on phone

Tags: codenameone

Since I am using the CN1 Calendar lib, I am not able to debug the app with calendar functions within the IDE and the Codename One simulator.

I just wanted to ask, how other developers are handling situations like this?

Comment: See edited answer for iOS debugging trick.

Answer (score 2):

You can debug your apps using DDMS in Android Studio or in Eclipse Neon with Android plugin.

Firstly, you need to enable developer mode on your Android device by tapping repeatedly the `Build Number` or `Build Version` under Settings -> About, it will activate your developer mode and then you can access the developer section under settings and allow `USB Debugging Mode`.

**Edit:**

For iOS, it's better to use Codename One error logging which will catch your exception and send it to you through email (Pro Account Required):

```
try {
    //Write the code you want to debug here
} catch (Exception ex) {
    Log.e(ex);
    Log.sendLog(); //This will send you a StackTrace (If any) through email
}
```

Comment: https://www.codenameone.com/how-do-i---use-the-include-sources-feature-to-debug-the-native-code-on-iosandroid-etc.html

Comment: Outside of subscribing to Pro account, is there a way to get regular (not necessarily Log.e() ) logs while debugging iOS apps made from Codename One on an iOS device? I am using Intellij.

Comment: Not that I know of. Although you could still get the message by calling `ex.getMessage()` and show it on a Dialog.

Comment: You could also debug natively by checking "Include source" when sending a build. Unfortunately, this also requires a Pro account.